# Understanding .bind(this) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, leaflet, this

```
constructor() {
      this._getPosition();
    }
_getPosition() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                this._loadMap.bind(this)
            ,() => {
                alert("could not get your position")
            })
            }
    }
```

In `this._loadMap.bind(this)` 
how do we know what the this in the bind parameter refers to?
For more context, here is the
`_loadMap()`  function

```
_loadMap(position) {
        const {latitude} = position.coords
        const {longitude} = position.coords
        let coords = [latitude, longitude]
        this.#map = L.map('map').setView(coords, 13); 
    
    L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(this.#map);
    L.marker(coords)
        .openPopup()
        .addTo(map)
        .bindPopup('You are here!')
        this.#map.on("click", function(mapE) {
            this.#mapEvent = mapE
            form.classList.remove("hidden")
            inputDistance.focus()
        })
    }
```

Basically, to sum everything up. The constructor executes the _getPosition function. We are using a geolocation API where the getCurrentPosition method accepts a success and an error callback. In the success callback, I want to call loadMap. The content of loadMap is not important, I just put it there in case anyone wants to see it. Now, when I do  `this._loadMap` only, I get undefined and I know that is the case because I am on strict mode and the this before the `_loadMap` will refer to undefined because we are inside a function. Now, when we do `this._loadMap.bind(this)` it works! But why?

Comment: maybe worth noting you can avoid `.bind` in most cases now that we have the arrow function in JS ... replace `this._loadMap.bind(this)` with `(...args) => this._loadMap(...args)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass `this._loadMap` to another function to use it as a callback, the relationship to `this` is broken. When `_loadMap()` is eventually called, it will not have a `this` value to use, and it will fail.

By using `.bind()`, you create a *new* function from the `_loadMap` method, one that is permanently associated with the value of `this` where you called `.bind()`.

The value of `this` in the context where you call `.bind()` is exactly the value of this wherever else you would use it in that context. Your constructor function calls `this._getPosition()`, so that function (`_getPosition()`) correctly has `this` bound to the object being constructed. In turn, in the call to `.bind()`, this is still that object.